# how to use self.crawler.engine.pause() from middleware in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to pause the scrapy engine (running crawler) from a middleware.

when I try to call self.crawler.engine.unpause() I receive this error:

'cRetry' object has no attribute 'crawler'

This is my middleware. How can I access the crawler object?

```
class cRetry(RetryMiddleware):

   errorCounter = 0


   def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if response.status in self.retry_http_codes:
            reason = response_status_message(response.status)
            return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response
        elif "error" in response.body:
            self.errorCounter = self.errorCounter + 1
            if self.errorCounter >= 10:
                self.crawler.engine.pause()
                os.system("restart.sh")
                print "Reset"
                time.sleep(10)
                self.crawler.engine.unpause()
                self.errorCounter = 0
            reason ="Restart Required"
            return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response
       ### end
        return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you could override the `__init__` and `from_crawler` methods to resemble something like:

```
class cRetry(RetryMiddleware):

    errorCounter = 0

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        super(cRetry, self).__init__(crawler.settings)
        self.crawler = crawler

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        # ...
```

The signature of `__init__` actually does not seem to matter, the [entry point for the main library](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#writing-your-own-extension) always is `from_crawler(cls, crawler)`. This is a [class method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) and takes the class name as first argument (then using it to call the constructor).

Comment: do I override in my spider.py file? I am already overriding init. when I add the crawler parameter like such I get an error: __init__(self, crawler, filename=None, domain=".com"), __init__() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)

Comment: You have to override them in cRetry. The [original ones](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/downloadermiddleware/retry.py) from RetryMiddleware do not pass `crawler` to `__init__`, but only `crawler.settings`. Thus you need to change `from_crawler` to pass on `crawler` and then adjust the `__init__` call to call the parent constructor (as you do not want to lose the other settings etc.)

Comment: I tried your solution, and now it throws: TypeError: unbound method from_crawler() must be called with cRetry instance as first argument (got CrawlerProcess instance instead). I suppose I have to change from_crawler(cls,**crawler**). Already tried from_crawler(cls,**self**) so it passes the instance of cRetry. But no success.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks aufziehvogel :-)

You suggestion worked with a small modifiction. @classmethod needs to be added, then it works like a charm.

```
class cRetry(RetryMiddleware):

    errorCounter = 0

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        super(cRetry, self).__init__(crawler.settings)
        self.crawler = crawler

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        # ...
```